# How can I retreive messages from Facebook Pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

I want to automatically, once a day, retrieve all (or all new) messages from a Facebook Page where I have admin rights.

I have investigated using Graph API, but in order to use this, I need to create an app. Moreover, in order to read messages, I need the 'read_page_mailboxes' permission. As far as I can understand, I need to demonstrate a proper app by screencast to the facebook team to get this permission granted, as explained here:
https://support.ladesk.com/704852-How-to-submit-Facebook-application-for-review
I don't have any such app, as I just plan to retrieve the messages by a web service interface.

I have also investigated [digi.me](https://get.digi.me/), which is a third-party tool that can take backups of the messages to a PC. The sync with facebook can by automated. The problem is that it is only possible to manually export the content out of the internal application storage, it can't be scheduled.

Do anyone know any way to periodically and automatically retrieve messages from Facebook Pages? Any method would be fine: commercial third-party tools, automatic forwarding to email, whatever works.